# View PDF of webService made with FPDF in a webView with POST parameters

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webservice in PHP which receives two variables through the POST method and generates a PDF through the FPDF library.

I have implemented this code in android studio but I can't see the PDF. The fact is that it does not give any error in execution, it just leaves the screen blank.

Do you know how it can be done?

```
Public class ConsultaPDF extends Activity {

    int id;
    String usuario;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta_pdf);

        id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id");
        usuario = getIntent().getExtras().getUsuario("usuario");

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        String postData = "id="+String.valueOf(id)+"&usuario="+usuario;
        String url = "http://www.mws.es/wsPDF.php";

        try {
            webview.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes( "UTF-8"));
            Log.i("WEBVIEW","Todo fue bien");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding","Encoding Exception" +e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A webview cannot display a pdf document. Only html and so.